# jquery the functions sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote the function Animal(), which displays text strings character by character:

```
var j=0;//counter derived fields 
var flag= -1;//Animal() performance indicator

function Animal(string) {
    flag=1;
    console.log('flag start:', flag );
    var a = ''; //The variable which will be entered character by character string
    var i= 0;
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    $('body').append(p);

    Anima();

    flag=0;
    console.log('flag end: ', flag);    
    //
    //
    function Anima() {  
        console.log('string start: ', j);
        a=a+string[i];
        i++;
        $('p:eq('+j+')').text(a);
        var timer = setTimeout(Anima, 100);
        if(i==string.length){
            clearTimeout(timer);
            j++;
            console.log('end: ', j);

        };
    };

Animal('dfkjdghksjdfhglksd');
Animal('11111111');
```

When I call function Animal() second time, it starts working, while first Animal() is working. How to make it works consistently?

Comment: You want them to run in order?

Comment: yes, and if u can help, i need to do it by using a function which will go over the array of strings `array={'string_1','string_2','string_3'}`

Answer (score 1):

## Explanation

It works in such way because `Animal` calls `setTimeout` which in result runs `Anima` asynchronously and makes it possible to run second instance of `Animal` concurrently.

## Possible solution

One option is to add a second parameter to the Animal function that's a callback to function that should be run when the first is done.

```
Animal('dfkjdghksjdfhglksd', function () {
  Animal('11111111');
});
```

And implementation:

```
function Animal(string, callback) {
  flag=1;
  console.log('flag start:', flag );
  var a = ''; //The variable which will be entered character by character string
  var i= 0;
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  $('body').append(p);

  Anima();

  flag=0;
  console.log('flag end: ', flag);    
  //
  //
  function Anima() {  
    console.log('string start: ', j);
    a=a+string[i];
    i++;
    $('p:eq('+j+')').text(a);
    var timer = setTimeout(Anima, 100);
    if (i==string.length) {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      j++;
      console.log('end: ', j);
      callback(); // here we run next Animal()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: o-o-okay, yes it helps. Thank u!
But what if i need to display an array of strings, like
     `array = [
        'ssssss',
        'AAAAA',
        '11111'
    ];`
so, i need to loop it in another function. but how 2 make it with a callback func?